# Unit testing @Sheduled with cron

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to test if the following scheduled method is executed at every midnight:

```
public class CacheService {

  /** Evicts token from the cache at midnight */
  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *", zone = "Europe/London")
  @CacheEvict(value = CacheConfig.AUTH_TOKEN, allEntries = true)
  public void clearCacheAtMidnight() {
    log.info("Scheduled cache clean at: " + Instant.now());
  }
}
```

I am using the following unit test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CacheServiceTest {

  @SpyBean private CacheService cacheService;

  @Test
  void shouldClearCacheAtMidnight() {
    Instant.now(Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"), ZoneId.of("Europe/London")));
    await()
            .atMost(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .untilAsserted(() -> verify(cacheService, atLeast(1)).clearCacheAtMidnight());
  }
}
```

But not joy. It works perfectly if I change from cron to fixrate.
I have a feeling that I am not overriding the system clock properly or I am not using the set Interval properly.

Any clue?

Comment: This seems like a silly test. The cron expression is declartive and you should trust it

Comment: Want to test the cache eviction at midnight. What is so silly about it?

Comment: You want to test clearchCacheAtMidnight. So simply call this method.

Comment: not quite. but thanks for your interest.

Comment: Since you're not the developer of Spring, you shouldn't be writing tests for the functionality **they** wrote. They don't write tests for your code either.

Comment: I removed the part about checking the caching eviction.

Comment: what if one forgets to add `EnableScheduling`, no test case fails and the application doesn't behave in the expected way either. might be a good case to test

Comment: Usually, these cases are handled with system tests or detect issue by application monitoring that some thing should be purged but not. Not a way to verify with unit test

Comment: I guess you should trust the annotation and test the method normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring internally use `CronSequenceGenerator` to parse the cron expression to find out next trigger time. If you want to test if you set up the cron expression correctly , you can reference to their [test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/test/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGeneratorTests.java) and write your own such as:

```
    @Test
    public void myTest() {

        CronSequenceGenerator cronSequenceGenerator = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 0 0 * * *",TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
        ZonedDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 6, 1, 9, 52, 0).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        ZonedDateTime expected = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        assertThat(cronSequenceGenerator.next(Date.from(date.toInstant()))).isEqualTo(Date.from(expected.toInstant()));

    }
```

I agree that that some testing guys will not suggest to do it as it tests the framework , but I would definitely include it as it is simple to write and at least I will be more confident that my cron expression is configured correctly especially some times we need to setup some non-trivial cron expression.